# NuxtJS: Disable console.log in production env

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I am looking for a way to disable `console.log()` for production env.  Something like putting the below code to `nuxt.config.js` or `index.js`:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
  console.log = () => {};
}
```

I tried it, but it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated.

My nuxt.config.js is here
https://gist.github.com/somaria/9a2b0e06497d13a35fe9eee141a15d07

Comment: You could try using `NUXT_ENV_` before your variable names during the build phase. Can you also share your nuxt.config.js file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nuxt's build process includes `terser`, which can be [configured](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#terser) to automatically remove console statements from your production build. You could set `build.terser.terserOptions`:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  build: {
    terser: {
      // https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, this can also be done with Plugins.

Under `Plugins` folder, we can create a file called `disableLogs.js` which can look like so:

```js
// plugins/disableLogs.js

export function disableLogs() {
  console.log = () => {};
  // or you can override any other stuff you want
}

process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? disableLogs() : null;
```

Then we can register this plugin to be used inside `nuxt.config.js`

```js
// nuxt.config.js
plugins: [
  { src: "~/plugins/disableLogs.js" },
  { src: "~/plugins/any-other-plugin.js"
],
```

This will run before instantiating the root Vue.js Application.

There are other things where you can configure it to run either client or server side, etc. More info here - https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#vue-plugins